# Year-Month-Date from numbers into text - Php

Tags: php, date, time

I have a slight problem, I have a date format coming from php my admin, which is: 1975-09-31 - this is in the format YYYY-MM-DD.

Is there a quicker way to turn those numbers into a text representation: e.g 1975-09-31 -> 31st September 1975, than to find out the month and Date and to go:

```
if($month == 1) { echo 'January'; }
```

and so on for each month and/or day?

In breif: "Is there a quick way that can turn 1975-09-31 into 31st September 1975, rather than listing out all the opportunities, and if so, how?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`date()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function combined with [`strtotime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
$today = '2011-11-08';
echo date("jS F Y", strtotime($today));
```

Outputs:

```
8th November 2011
```

And a sidenote regarding your example: There's no September 31 as there's only 30 days in that month ;)

Comment: Thanks, that works! On a sidenote, is there a way, like this to put a th or nd or st at the end of the number, so it is grammatically correct, but without listing the numbers again?

Comment: There is, forgot to add it in my solution. Updated my answer now :)

Comment: Np, don't forget to mark it as an accepted answer by ticking the box to the left of the answer :)

Comment: Note that the date() function isn't locale-aware so if you ever have to port your code to work in a different language you may run into problems. Easier to use strftime() from the start.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are easier ways than that. You need to look into functions like [strftime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)
e.g.

```
$outputDate = strftime( 'format string', strtotime( $inputDate ) );
```

Comment: thanks, that seems to be on the right track, but the site says that this should display it as  6th June 1983, but it doesn't do that: 
   $outputDate = strftime( '%d/$m/%y', strtotime( '06-08-1983) );

Thanks

Comment: Your $inputDate should be a date in YYYY-MM-DD format (or another format that strtotime can handle). Dates like DD-MM-YYYY are difficult to handle as there could be confusion between European and US formats (DD-MM-YYYY vs MM-DD-YYYY).

Comment: Plus in your date format you need to use % signs and not $ signs.

Comment: What I need is to put the month into a text - e.g January if it is YYYY-01-DDDD

Comment: Sure $outputDate = strftime( '%B', strtotime( 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) ); That will output 'January' if MM is 01.